# How to write a code for x_train row values addition, subtraction will affect to predict the next future value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have a dataset with three inputs and trying to predict next value of X1 with the combination of previous inputs values.

My three inputs are X1, X2, X3, X4.

So here I am trying to predict next future value of X1. To predict the next X1 these four inputs combination affect with.

I just want to say that while prediction the value , These four inputs affect with addition and subtraction and give the prediction value.

Here I wrote the code for addition and subtraction inside the x_train. Then it run in lstm model.

Then I tried to predict it with x_test_n value. But it gave me an error `Error when checking input: expected lstm_16_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1530, 1)`

Here is my code:

```
def predict(x_train):
    s = np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: row[0] + row[1] - row[2] - row[3], arr=data)
    return model.predict(s)
```

lstm model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, x_train.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(8))  # return a single vector of dimension 32
model.add(Dense(1))
```

predict with

```
pred = predict(x_test)
```

Gave me this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you supply to `model.predict` need to have the same dimension as `x_train.shape[2]`.

Looking at the error message, this is 3. In the predict function you are summing 4 values, giving an input vector of size 1.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply . So can you help me to solve this problem with code? I am not having any idea how to change the code